# Django Choice Queries with annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am stucked in django annotate query.

here is certain Model I have been working.

```
class Claim(model.Model)
     CLAIMS_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (2, PROCESSING),
    (1, ACCEPTED),
    (0, REJECTED)
) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choice=CLAIMS_STATUS_CHOICES)
```

problem is  I don't want  to annotate processing choice but I just want to get individual status count  of accepted and rejected.
Here is what I tried.

```
claim = Claim.objects.filter(Q(status=1) | Q(status=0))
total_status_count = claim.count()
status_counts = Claim.objects.filter(Q(status=1) |Q(status=0)).annotate(count=Count('status')).values('count', 'status')
```

but I am getting multiple rejected and accepted queries
this is what I got as op

```
 [
        {
            "total_claims": 3,
            "status_count": [
                {
                    "status": "1",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "status": "0",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "status": "1",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

what I wanted

```
 [
        {
            "total_claims": 3,
            "status_count": [
                {
                    "status": "1",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "status": "0",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

Any help regarding this?

Comment: You can accomplish it without using `annotate()` just by using `filter()` and `count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Claim.objects.exclude(status=2).values('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done a similar task in my project, where I have to count the total completed and in progress projects. In my case, the scenario is, every project have a status.
In the project model, status is a choice field which have choices (uploaded, inprogress, inreview, and completed).

I'm posting the query here, maybe someone finds it helpful. In an API, write the following query:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

 project_counts = Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).aggregate(
        total=Count('id'),
        inprogress=Count('id', Q(status=Project.ProjectStatus.IN_PROGRESS)),
        completed=Count('id', Q(status=Project.ProjectStatus.COMPLETED)))
```

and then return the response like this.

```
return response.Response({
        'total': project_counts['total'] | 0,
        'inprogress': project_counts['inprogress'] | 0,
        'completed': project_counts['completed'] | 0
    })
```